# Open pdf extern from android app without acrobat reader

Tags: android, pdf

I want to open a pdf from my android app in an external viewer. When I have installed Acrobat Reader everything works great. But when Acrobar reader isn't installed he can't find a viewer.
But another app on the same device is able to open pdfs in google drive.
I want this behaviour, too. What I have to do, that this works for my app?

So I open pdfs at the moment:

```
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'));
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File("fileName")), "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        if (!this.context.getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).isEmpty()) {
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Intent.createChooser()` : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser

```
Intent intent=...//your intent
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open PDF");
startActivity(chooser);
```

**EDIT:**

For google drive the intent action is Intent.ACTION_SEND, and you need to set extras make your intent with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + your_file_path));
```

Comment: Hi, the chooser works, but I dont get google drive as option.

Comment: @BHuelse, edited, try with the action Intent.ACTION_SEND

Comment: @BHuelse, i forgot the extras in the answer

Comment: Hmm, ok it loads my pdf now to google drive, ow. buts not what I want. Another strange thing is, that I just get acrobat as option. I have installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pdfviewer too, but this is not an option. This isn't right or?

Comment: Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_GET_CONTENT, maybe this is what you need, or take a look at other combinations of intents and actions.